# Alert using echo in php

Tags: javascript, php

[Kindly go though the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5ap.jpg)I want to show an alert message. My insertion is successful and the header also works fine but `alert()` is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if(mysql_query($query))//query execution
{
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> ';
    echo 'alert("message successfully Inserted")';//msg
    echo '</script>';
    header('location:madesignin.php');//header jump to the page
    exit;       
}
else//data will be not inserted if condition fails
{
    echo "DATA NOT INSERTED";
}
```

Comment: `'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> alert("message successfully Inserted")</script>'` write in single line.

Comment: write your echo statement into <script > tag.

Comment: hello sir , i tried this out in a single line , but still it is not working.

Comment: Your `if` condition is doomed to fail. *IF* the redirect works, you won't see the script that comes before it, if the `<script>` succeeds, you likely won't have a redirect.

Comment: @MayankVadiya can you provide the syntax of echo in script tag?? thanks

Comment: Most likely because you are redirecting before the JS is loaded, php executes and THEN JS does, try commenting out the `header();` line and see if your alert doesn't show then.

Comment: echo "<script>alert('your message')</script>"; @RahulTikhe

Comment: Also stop ising `mysql_*` that series of functions are deprecated and unsafe.

Comment: @ Rasclatt sir , my insertion is taking place into database.how can i figure out this issue?

Comment: You should be converting all your `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
if(mysql_query($query))//query execution
{
   echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
                alert("message successfully Inserted");
                window.location = "madesign.php";
        </script>';
}
else
{
    echo 'DATA INSERTED';
}
```

```js
alert("message successfully Inserted");
window.location = "madesign.php";
```

Comment: You have a syntax error `'DATA INSERTED"`. You are mixing a single quote with double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Alert will not work in above situation because redirecting and javascript alert() is calling same time. So it will skip javascript and redirect to page.

Try

```
if(mysql_query($query))//query execution
{
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> ';
echo 'if(!alert("message successfully Inserted")) {';//msg
echo ' location.href="madesignin.php"';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
exit;       
}
else//data will be not inserted if condition fails
{
  echo "DATA NOT INSERTED";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use Javascript alert. There's a way to send a message after redirecting to a new page using php.

```
        header("location: thank_you.php?success_message=thanks for shopping with us");
```

if the statement doesn't run;

```
else{
    header("location: index.php");
}
exit;
```

then in the new page called thank_you.php for example, you should display the message;

```
            <?php if (isset($_GET['success_message'])){ ?>
            <h3 style="color: gold"><?php echo $_GET['success_message']; ?></h3>
                                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not Recomended. echo `$_GET['success_message']` will lead to XSS. You should sanitize

Comment: How do you mean?